# Diagonals of Pascal's Triangle

Tags: integration, binomial-coefficients, constants

Preface: For images with *r* and *x*, *r*=*k* and *x*=*n*

Recently, I have started looking closer at Pascal's Triangle (because it's fascinating) and I wanted to try to make a general form for the function of each diagonal. Essentially, the diagonals are represented by *k*, where *k*=1 refers to the first diagonal which is only filled with ones, *k*=2 is the second diagonal which is filled with the natural numbers.

The first diagonal would be *k*=1, where the function would be n. Then, *k*=2 would give us *[(n^2)/2 + Cn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaotg.png)* . I used integration to give me *k*=2 because *k*=1 is the rate of change of *k*=2, so integration *k*=1 should yield *k*=2.
However, when integrating *k*=1, the integral should not have an *n* multiplied by the integration constant, it should be a lone *+C*. This I am confused on.

I learned that integration works even less as *k* increases, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4ZBm.png) 
where I try to integrate *k*=2. The function is slightly inaccurate and also requires a random bonus *n* to be attached to the integration constant. Why doesn't integrating work?

I have recognized that the lowest order term has a pattern to [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIjiX.png). This leads me to believe there is an answer, I'm just not sure how to reach it.

My goal is to be able to determine the function of the *n*th term at a certain value of *k*, which I decided to label *a*.

Edit: Fixed *x*->*n*  and *r*->*k*

Edit: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL476.png) is an image that can help clarify the process I am going through and how I used integration.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not at all clear what functions you are trying for. You introduce $r$ in a way that is confusing, introduce "$x$" without indicating what it is at all, talk about integration without indicating what the integration is supposed to be accomplishing and why. The coefficients in Pascal's triangle are given by $${n\choose k} = \frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$ The diagonals are what you get when you hold $k$ (or $n-k$) constant while varying $n$. How is what you are after different from that?

Comment: I edited the post so it is much more coherent.

Comment: The diagonals of the triangle are sums of finite numbers of integers. Integrals are designed to solve a very different kind of problem. What made you consider integrals as a possible way to compute the diagonals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made some interesting observations on the structure of Pascal's triangle.

First, you should note that the diagonals you are referring to are actually defined by $f(k=a)=\binom{n}{a}$; that is, what you call $f(k=1)$ (for example) is actually $\binom{n}{1}$ for each $n$. Now, the [hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) will tell you that
$$\sum_{i=r}^n \binom{i}{r} = \binom{n+1}{r+1},$$
so that the values of $f(k=a)$ are the sequential sums of $f(k=a-1)$. Thus for example for $f(k=5)$ we get $6=1+5$, $21=1+5+15$, $56 = 1+5+15+35$.

So there are a couple of ways you might think about finding a concrete formula. First, of course, the binomial coefficients have a reasonably explicit form:
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}{k!}.$$
For small values of $k$, you can write this down explicitly, as you have; of course, the degrees of the result as a polynomial in $n$ gets larger and larger. You might also think about using what you (may) know about sums of powers. For example, to derive $f(k=3)$ you could do
\begin{align*}
  f(k=3)(n) &= \binom{n}{3} = \sum_{i=2}^n\binom{i}{2} \\
   &= \sum_{i=2}^n \left(\frac{i^2}{2} - \frac{i}{2}\right) \\
   &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^2 - \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} i\right) \\
   &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{(n-1)(n)(2n-1)}{6} - \frac{(n-1)(n)}{2}\right) \\
   &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2n^3 - 3n^2+n}{6} - \frac{n^2-n}{2}\right) \\
   &= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2n^3 - 6n^2 + 4n}{6} \\
   &= \frac{n^3}{6} - \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{3},
\end{align*}
which agrees with your formula. You will not succeed in finding a simple closed formula in terms of $n$ and $k$ however.

If you want to look more into representations of sums of powers of consecutive integers, which is obviously related to your question, you could look [here](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/sums-of-powers-of-positive-integers-introduction) or in many other places.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The $a \ge 1$ value of diagonal $d\ge 0$ is $\Pi_{i=0}^{d-1}(a + i)/d!$. e.g. diagonal 0 is always 1, diagonal 1 is $a = 1, 2, 3...$, diagonal 2 is $a(a+1)/2$, diagonal 3 is $a(a+1)(a+2)/3!$, etc...

In terms of $n >= d$ this can be written as $\Pi_{i=0}^{d-1}(n - d + i + 1)/d!$, e.g. diagonal 3 crosses row $n$ where the value is $n(n-1)(n-2)/3!$; diagonal 3 crosses row 5 at $5(4)(3)/3! = 10$